# Finding the limit for the level curves of a multivariable function

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, curves

A surface is defined by $$q(x,y) = \begin{cases}
-\log_2\Bigl(\frac{1}{x^2+y^2-2} + 2\Bigr),  &(x,y)\in D \\
1, &(x,y) = (0,0)
\end{cases}$$

Find D if q is over the maximal domain. I believe
$$ D = {(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 \mid x^2 + y^2 > \frac{9}{4} }$$

Do the level curves approach a limit as $$ q \rightarrow \infty $$

and if so, what is this limiting level curve.